# Three.js DracoLoader - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Promise')

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am working on a Three.js project and using DracoLoader for mesh compression. However, I am encountering the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Promise') at $jscomp.polyfill (draco_wasm_wrapper.js:3:155) at draco_wasm_wrapper.js:4:9

I've included the necessary polyfill (https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js), and my importmap for Three.js looks like this:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.160.1/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've checked the polyfill URL, and it seems to be working. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with DracoLoader in Three.js, and how can I resolve this 'Promise' error?

Thanks in advance for your help!